# Axios is not getting response on first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new in React JS and trying to get the data inside useEffect and I have a separate function for my api, but when I check the data.next in console.log there is no data in the first load but after adding few changes it works fine but still has an error when I refresh the page. Also, I noticed when I tried to console.log inside of function where the Axios or api declared, there's already a data in the first load of an application. Did anyone encounter this issue? Or my approach is wrong?

Here are my codes
/src/App.js

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await service.apiPokemon.fetchAll();
    console.log(res.data.next)
}, []);
```

/src/api/pokemon.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

export const fetchAll = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(URL);
        console.log(res.data.next);
        
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. Your content is loaded before fetching the data. To solve this, you can add a condition to not render your content until you get the data:

```
  let [pokemonsList, setPokemonsList] = useState([])

  // Your useEffect hook to fetch data on mount

  return (
    { pokemonsList.lenght > 0 && // If you are sure you'll receive pokemons
      <div> {pokemonList.map((pokemon) => (
         <p> {pokemon.name} </p>
      )} </div>
    }
  )
```

Now, you'll only see the names of the pokemons when you have the list.
You can also add a loading message in case the response takes time with Redux and selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think my question is a bit confusing.

In my useEffect in App component, there is an useEffect where my separate file or api has been called, inside of api file, when I check in console log, I already get a response but when I'm returning the data and check in App component there is no response.

Comment: After trying working again on this error, for some reason it works fine after I run again this project. Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: I hope it was helpful for you.